# Cannot update MySQL Database, error in sql part

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Im trying to update a table in MySQL database, but the data cannot be updated.

the value for $id is 2 and $status is empty.

```
echo $id;

echo $status;

$sql="UPDATE maklumat_tempahan

SET

status = '$status',

WHERE id_tempahan = '$id' "; 

mysql_select_db('psmbaru');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
?>

 <?php    if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Permohonan Anda Dalam Proses\n";
mysql_close($conn);}?>
```

This is the error that came out
Could not update data: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id_tempahan = '2'' at line 7

Comment: Remove `,` after `$status`. I foresee a couple of users trying to score some easy rep here.

Comment: Remove the comma after `status = '$status',`

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You may also be **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: @asprin — I find the best defense against that is to create a community wiki answer instead of a comment.

Comment: @Quentin Nice idea. Hadn't thought of that before

Answer (score 2):

remove `,` after `$status`

```
$sql="UPDATE maklumat_tempahan

SET

status = '$status'

WHERE id_tempahan = '$id' ";
```

Comment: HELP, SQLi attack here. where is my defense ?

Comment: @KarelG — There's no actual evidence that `$status` and `$id` aren't sanitized before the code in the question starts, and if they aren't then this answer doesn't introduce a vulnerability that isn't inherent in the OP's code design.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, remove comma after => status = '$status'**,**
and are you sure not to add mysql_real_escape_string() for your input brother?